# 2015 27" iMac unexpectedly wakes from sleep after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: imac, sleep-wake

Before upgrading to Catalina, my 2015 27" iMac would reliably stay sleeping as long as I had manually put it to sleep from the Apple menu.

After the Catalina upgrade, I'd say at least 50% of the time, the iMac wakes itself up if it has been sleeping from more than about 5 hours (so, quite often overnight).

Wake for Network Access and Enable Power Nap are UNchecked.

I have a wired keyboard and a Logitech mouse that works via Bluetooth.

In Preferences-->Bluetooth->Advanced, "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer" is UNchecked

Here are the results from *pmset -g* :

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 proximitywake        1
 standby              0
 standbydelaylow      86400
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        0
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         10
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by sharingd, coreaudiod, UserEventAgent)
 halfdim              1
 autorestart          0
 disksleep            10
```

I also ran the Terminal command *log show --style syslog | fgrep “Wake reason"* after a recent awakening, and the last log entries were:

```
2020-06-11 20:59:49.029149-0700 localhost powerd[145]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>" identity: "<private>"

2020-06-11 21:51:50.752175-0700 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: RTC XHC1 (Alarm)

2020-06-11 21:51:50.752176-0700 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: RTC XHC1 (Alarm)
```

First, I don't know how to interpret these results.

Second, what is quite odd is that this last entry is on June 11. BUT, when I got up on the morning of June 12, I checked to see if the iMac had awakened itself, and it had not. At 8:30am on 2020-06-12, the iMac was asleep. BUT, at 10am when I went back again, it was awake.

So, shouldn't there be a log entry for the wake that occurred sometime between 8:30am and 10am on June 12?

Any help would be appreciated.